# Error while logging into a new environment using wso2 apictl tool

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am getting following error when I try to log into an environment using wso2 apictl tool.

> apictl: Error in connecting. Reason: Post "https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/
> ogin.jsp": Auto redirect is disabled
> Exit status 1.

I am running the command `apictl login dev -u admin -p admin -k` in APICTL command line.

I am using WSO2 APIM 3.1.0 and it is up and running and I am even able to access APIM Management Console with admin credentials. I have tried with apictl-3.1.2 as well as apictl-3.1.3. Not sure what the issue is. Need suggestions to resolve this?

[image]

I also verified in the apictl terminal and the environment is present.
[image]

Comment: What is your api manager version? Each API Manager version has a compatible apictl or relevant tool

Comment: Based on your error msg, it seems like you are using a wrong tool

Comment: You need to use APIM 3.1.0 version, if you are using the apictl 3.1.x versions. Or else if you are using APIM 3.0.0, you can try with https://github.com/wso2/product-apim-tooling/releases/tag/v3.0.1

Comment: I am using APIM 3.1.0. I tried with apictl-3.1.2 as well as apictl-3.1.3. Getting the same error in both the cases.

Comment: The issue is fixed when i tried with apictl-3.1.0. Thanks for the suggestions.